# LogisticRegression predict 1 if probability to 1 is bigger than 0.7

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

in sklearn LogisticRegression

```
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)    
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

it give 1 if the probability to 1  is bigger than 0.5.

I want to change it that it give 1 if the probability to 1  is bigger than 0.7

Comment: Maybe you can try model.predict_proba() and subsequently ">=0.7" to find the predicted class?

Comment: thanks for the answer but I knew about model.predict_proba. I thought that maybe function predict has some option to "play" with the probability . it seens it not have and we need to do the "long way" which mean - use model.predict_proba and create new binery variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **model.predict_proba** instead of **mode.predict**, as it will give you probabilities. On that you can use required threshold.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: thanks for the answer but I knew about model.predict_proba.  I thought that maybe function  predict has some option to "play" with the probability .  it seens it not have and we need to do the "long way" which mean - use model.predict_proba and create new binery variable